# Views and Categories...?

Tags: drupal, view, nodes, categories

it's about this page: http://veagues.com/

Hey guys,

I've made a block-view with drupal that let's me sort my videos by a certain category, in this case "funny","epic","plays", "contest"...

The problem is: When you sort it by the certain category and click on a video and continue to click the "next" button, you will go threw all videos, instead of only the videos of the category...

My Question is: How can I put a filter on the nodes when i apply another category on the bottom block?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Views, you should be able to filter the main block by the same taxonomy term.

Try adding a Contextual Filter to that block too. If there's a taxonomy term ID in the URL the block gets filtered by that Term ID and if there's no result, the block shows all the videos.

EDIT -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

You may need to try & understand what goes on when you make a selection in Drupal.

1/ The taxonomy term page will list all the content affixed with a specific term. The term tid can be seen in the URL, unless an alias have been created. A block can retrieve that term id, whether there is an alias or not.

2/ The node page will give you access to a specific node, but any block on that page should be able to access the term id of that specific node.

If you know where you are, it becomes easier to retrieve the info you're looking for. On the other hand,  you may have to reconfigure a specific page in order to add the necessary extra block...
 

That can be done with templates but you could also have a look at [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

The Panels UI makes it easier to configure the page you're looking for without having to mess with code or templates, or both.
There's a lot of free video tutorials out there, search for Views & Panels.

If you want to have a look at preprocess functions, you will definitely need to download the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module...

...but have a look at these sites first:
http://codekarate.com/
http://drupalize.me/
http://buildamodule.com

Comment: The problem is, that it is not a block :D :-/ It's just the main content... Or can I make a view for my main content block too?

Comment: You certainly can! Just create a block view that retrieves all your videos and add the contextual filter.

Comment: But the nodes are displayed in that region 24/7... So if I add a block I've got the videos twice...? Or am I stupid right now

Comment: You may need to create a new page and set it as frontpage in the Site Information menu... By default, Drupal list all the nodes on the default frontpage

Comment: This is what I tried: I created a new page and called it /veagues... So the frontpage would directly link to it... on veagues I got the newest video first and tried to add a contextual filter to it... but when I change the filter on the bottom, it doesn't apply on the videos at the top... vice versa when I expose the form as a block and put it above the videosection, it doesn't apply on the videosection ...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to doing this via the Views UI only, usually I would create my own template and probably get all my arguments with a preprocess function... If you're new to Drupal, that may not be the most obvious way... Right now, I'm just guessing... You could try creating your page in Views, that would take care of the main video. Set a contextual filter. Then for the selection , use an attachment and set the same contextual filter... It is also possible that the solution you have right now could work provided you spend more time on the configuration of your filters...

Comment: I have one last question... If I create a new page and then click on a video in my videoselection... Isn't it a different page then? Because it goes then to "veague-1" or something? How can I provide the same page if I click on different videos? I guess I'm missing a big point right now, but I'm quite confused :-D

Comment: Could you probably send me a link on preprocess functions? I can't quite understand it in the drupal documentation, is there any good tutorial for this? Is it then possible to use the preprocess functions to get the current contextual filter and then adapt the mai ncontent to it?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I will take a look at panels and at these pages... Seems like I got a lot of work to do! :D